# Extract the highest place value digit from numbers in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, digits

I have a python dataframe with a column called error codes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'errorcodes1':[6321,235,314,421,5346,514,4,3415,136,216,34,623])
```

I need a function that outputs: [6,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,1,2,3,6].

I have thought of converting each error code into a string, and extracting element [0]. However, that involves string manipulation, casting from and into an integer, which is likely to be slow. Is there a faster way?

Comment: `df['errorcodes1'].apply(lambda x:int(str(x)[0]))`

Comment: BTW: did you check how slow is your idea? Maybe it is not slow. You search faster method but you don't know how slow is your idea. How do you expected to compare both versions ?

Comment: This is based on experience with other languages like Fortran 95, MATLAB and C++. String manipulations and type casting are among the slower operations one can have.

Comment: pandas use C/C++ code for this so it can be faster then pure Python. The only idea to do this without string is `log()` but I don't know how much faster it will be - you would have to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made test which method is faster - `log` or `str` - and both gives similar result but `str` is little faster. If you don't convert `str` to `int` then it is even faster. You can also use `ord()` instead of `int()` to make it faster.

```
e1 = time.time()
results = [int(str(n)[0]) for n in numbers]
e2 = time.time()
print('int(str): {:.10f}'.format(e2-e1))

e1 = time.time()
results = [n//10**int(math.log(n, 10)) for n in numbers]
e2 = time.time()
print('     log: {:.10f}'.format(e2-e1))

e1 = time.time()
results = [str(n)[0] for n in numbers]
e2 = time.time()
print('     str: {:.10f}'.format(e2-e1))

e1 = time.time()
results = [ord(str(n)[0])-ord('0') for n in numbers]
e2 = time.time()
print('ord(str): {:.10f}'.format(e2-e1))
```

Result

```
int(str): 0.0000424385
     log: 0.0000514984
     str: 0.0000197887
ord(str): 0.0000286102
```

---

To make better test I used module `timeit` which runs code many times and calculate average time.

I also check code with `df.apply()` and with converting `df` to `list` and later converting `list` to `df`. All shows that time used to get first digit is so small then it is not important in all calculations

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import time
import timeit

def test1():
    results = [int(str(n)[0]) for n in numbers]

def test1b():
    results = [ord(str(n)[0]) - ord('0') for n in numbers]

def test1c():
    results = [str(n)[0] for n in numbers]

def test2():
    results = [n//10**int(math.log(n, 10)) for n in numbers]

def test3():
    df['number'] = df['errorcodes1'].apply(lambda n:int(str(n)[0]))

def test3b():
    df['number'] = df['errorcodes1'].apply(lambda n:ord(str(n)[0])-ord('0'))

def test3c():
    df['number'] = df['errorcodes1'].apply(lambda n:str(n)[0])

def test4():    
    df['number'] = df['errorcodes1'].apply(lambda n:n//10**int(math.log(n, 10)))

def test5():
    numbers = df['errorcodes1'].to_list()
    results = [int(str(n)[0]) for n in numbers]
    df['number'] = results

def test6():
    numbers = df['errorcodes1'].to_list()
    results = [n//10**int(math.log(n, 10)) for n in numbers]
    df['number'] = results

df = pd.DataFrame({'errorcodes1':[6321,235,314,421,5346,514,4,3415,136,216,34,623]})
numbers = df['errorcodes1'].to_list()

print('list log()      : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test2, number=1000)))
print('list int(str()) : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test1, number=1000)))
print('list ord(str()) : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test1b, number=1000)))
print('list str()      : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test1c, number=1000)))
print('---')
print('df.apply(log())      : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test4, number=1000)))
print('df.apply(int(str())) : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test3, number=1000)))
print('df.apply(ord(str())) : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test3b, number=1000)))
print('df.apply(str())      : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test3c, number=1000)))
print('---')
print('df -> list int(str()) -> df : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test5, number=1000)))
print('df -> list log()      -> df : {:.5f}'.format(timeit.timeit(test6, number=1000)))
```

Result:

```
list log()      : 0.01505
list int(str()) : 0.00917
list ord(str()) : 0.00713
list str()      : 0.00463
---
df.apply(log())      : 0.62433
df.apply(int(str())) : 0.61940
df.apply(ord(str())) : 0.60435
df.apply(str())      : 0.64205
---
df -> list int(str()) -> df : 0.27188
df -> list log()      -> df : 0.27696
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are prohibited from doing conversion to `str` you might harness Briggs' logarithm for that task following way:

```
import math
numbers = [6321,235,314,421,5346,514,4,3415,136,216,34,623]
def first_digit(n):
    return n//10**int(math.log(n, 10))
for n in numbers:
    print(n, first_digit(n), sep='\t')
```

Output:

```
6321    6
235 2
314 3
421 4
5346    5
514 5
4   4
3415    3
136 1
216 2
34  3
623 6
```

Explanation: first I detect number of digits in number, using before mentioned logarithm, then I check how many `10**(number_of_digits)` will fit into given number using integer division (`//`).

Answer (score 0):

i think string manipulation is best or you can try on each data ceil division by length